# How decide what to put in a MOSS site template/definition

Tags: moss, list, definition

When deciding on what elements to include in a MOSS site definition, i.e. lists, libraries etc. is there a rule of thumb on how best to make this decision?

Would appreciate anyones suggestions.

All the best

Comment: Andrew Connell has a good point about this issue in [this blog post](http://andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/02/15/You-dont-need-to-create-site-definitions.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This what I've done several times:

- Copy one of the definition
  existentes.
- Modify this copy in the way I need,
  deleting the list and all the other
  stuff I don't really need.
- Create features which will add
  funcionality to the site.
- Include these features in the site
  template.

I think features (and solutions) are better than other things to add functionality on sites.